# JavaSoundRecorder TargetDataLine does not close?

Tags: java, audio

I have a JavaSoundRecorder that I have created as shown below. When I create an object of the class and call the finish() function the line does not stop/close and remains active (does not reach null state). Meaning that I can only make a single recording with the recorder. What can I do to fix this issue?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.util.Set;

public class JavaSoundRecorder {
    
    private TargetDataLine line;
    
    private AudioFileFormat.Type fileType;
    
    private File savedWav;
    
    private AudioFormat audioForm;
    
    private DataLine.Info info;
    
    public int errorNum;

    public void setFile(File savedWav) {
        this.savedWav = savedWav;
    }
    
    /*constructs class*/ 
    public JavaSoundRecorder() {        
        fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
        audioForm = getAudioFormat();
        info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioForm);
    }
    
    /*
     * Defines an audio format
    */
    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean BigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels , signed, BigEndian);
        return format;
    }
    
    /*Captures the sound and records in WAV fiLE, creates a new thread for recording*/
    protected int startRecording(String path) {
        setFile(new File(path));
        errorNum = 0;
        
        if(line == null) {

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        //check if system supports the data line
                        if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                            System.out.println("not supported")
                        }
                        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                        line.open(audioForm);
                        line.start();

                        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
                        //write recoding to file..
                        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, savedWav);
                    } 
                    catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
                        errorNum = 3;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch(IOException e) {
                        errorNum = 4;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
    });
    thread2.start();
    }
    return errorNum;
 }

/*stops recording*/
public void finish() {
    line.stop();
    line.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at using loose coupling pattern. The `finish()` method should *suggest* to the recording thread to do the work of closing and cleaning up, not actually do that work itself. Thus have `finish()` flip a *boolean* named something like `isRunning` to `false`. The boolean can be `volatile` to help ensure the change in value is immediately read across the different threads.

With this, move the code which closes and cleans up to the end of the `run()` method, and surround the code that executes the `write()` with a `while(isRunning)` block.

Now, I'm not up enough on the details to know off the top of my head the exact changes required, but I think you will also have to refactor a bit so the writing is an action that repeats, that repeatedly gives control back to the enclosing `while()` after each write operation.